# Referencing input in specific form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm catching data-async of form created using twitter bootstrap in following manner:

```
 $('form[data-async]').live('submit', function(event) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));
        var target_id = $target[0].id;

  ....
 }
```

I'd like to reference input with name "username" in the form in question... I tried $form.username, $form['username'], but to no avail, and I couldn't find how to get the input. I know I can use

```
  $('#formid input[name=bla]')
```

but since I've already got form object, I'd like to use that if possible.

Thanks

Comment: can you post some relevant markup

Comment: Btw, `.live()` has been deprecated in favour of `.on()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your submit handler, the `username` input field can be referenced simply by:

```
this.elements['username']
```

No need for fancy jQuery :)

**Update**

Didn't realize `elements` is a fairly recent addition. Before that you could use:

```
this.username
```

**Update 2**

A shimmed version would look like this:

```
var field = this.elements ? this.elements['username'] : this.username;
```

Comment: I did some testing with 50000 iterations... Your solution takes ~400ms, .find() takes ~5500ms and context thingy takes ~7000ms. So I like this best, but could you elaborate on "recent addition"? How can I make sure on which browsers will my code work?

Comment: @Marin Before `.elements` the input boxes would be properties of the form element itself, so that should still work. this can be shimmed though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.find()`:

```
var $input = $form.find('input[name=bla]');
```

*edit* — commenter Jack points out that there's also the HTML5 "elements" property of the form DOM element. That lets you get to inputs by name or id, or by numeric index.

```
var input = this.elements['bla'];
```

Access by name is complicated by the fact that the mechanism also considers element "id" properties (in fact those take precedence, I think).

Comment: What happened to simple JavaScript? ;-)

Comment: @Jack well the deal where field names of form inputs become properties of the form DOM element isn't really standard, and I think it was a terrible idea due to the obvious problem of collisions with other important form properties. There is however, the HTML5 "elements" property.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize `elements` is a HTML5 property ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form object as [**context with selector**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to find the elements within context.

Syntax: `jQuery( selector [ , context ]  )`

```
$('input[name=bla]', $form );
```

You can use this as it represents your form.

```
$('form[data-async]').live('submit', function(event) {

     $('input[name=bla]', this ); // this is your form

 })
```

Comment: That assumes the input element has an id of `input`? :)

Comment: I like this more than find(), but you need to "lose the #" as Jack says above :)

Comment: Thank you guys I had typo and just removed the #

Comment: @Marin This runs a `find()` under the covers as well.